# Failed to send an email to the email sender dynamic in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, sendmail

My code is like this :

```
 public function sendMail(array $data)
    { 
        $data = explode('#', $data['id']);
        $email_from = Auth::user()->email;
        $email_to = $data[4];
        $subject = 'Send Email Test';

        $data_user = ['user_name' => $data[1], 'full_name' => $data[2].' '.$data[3] ];

        $sent = Mail::send('backend.auth.success_approved', $data_user, function ($mail) use ($email_to, $email_from, $subject)
                {
                    $mail->from($email_from)
                         ->to($email_to)
                         ->subject($subject);
                });
    }
```

My configuration in mail.php :

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'myemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'myname'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

It has successfully to send email. But it did not dynamic sender.
It is the email sender of mail.php

How to keep its dynamic sender?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to send mail from dynamic sender if you are using Gmail server. For security purpose Gmail is converting your sender address to your default address. To prevent spamming many email server (like Gmail, Hotmail etc) don't let you do this. As an example you can send email from Barak Obama's email address.

If it is very important to send email from dynamic address for you, you can use raw php function `mail()`

```
$header = 'From: [FEEDBACK] <'.$email_from.'>'."\r\n".'Reply-To:'.$email_from."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$sent = mail('myemail@gmail.com',$subject,$body,$header);
```

> This code will not work in localhost, unless you configure your xampp or wampp or mampp

Comment: It's working in localhost. But I have problem. When I change mail host to : 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ssl://secure.emailsrvr.com'), there is error message : Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265: Connection could not be established with host ssl://secure.emailsrvr.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. #0]. How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: @mosestoh May be it's only `secure.emailsrvr.com` and if you want to use `ssl` change this line `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl')`

Comment: I set up like this : http://pastebin.com/1GCUPsun. There is no error, but the e-mail could not be sent

Comment: @mosestoh If possible upload your project to any hosting. As far I know `mail()` doesn't work in localhost.

Comment: Right, it is still in localhost. But before I use smtp gmail, it can send email in localhost

Comment: When I use smtp gmail, it can send email in localhost

Comment: was the sender email changed to your gmail address than?

Comment: Yes, email sender according to the email set in mail.php